# Enabling just email and facebook in sharekit

Tags: ios, facebook, share, sharekit

I am a newbie to sharekit. Need some help. I would like to enable just the email and facebook options when I click the share button.. I do not want the options delicious and twitter so on... How do I that? Need some guidance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)

Edit `SHKSharers.plist` to include only sharers you need.

Comment: I was looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817538/ios-sharekit-selecting-the-required-sharing-services

Answer (score 0):

```
favoriteSharers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKFacebook", @"SHKMail", nil];
return favoriteSharers;
```

Change this in favoriteSharersForType function in SHK.m file...

Comment: is it the best way to do that, since we don't want to change the sub project